# "my_array.push (... data)" generates an error. How can I fix it?

Tags: angularjs

My code is done in angular.js and I am trying to add several elements to the array. something like that:

```
$scope.my_array=[];
$scope.my_array.push({"element":1});
var data= {"element":2},{"element":3}
$scope.my_array.push(...data);
console.log($scope.my_array) => [{"element":1},{"element":2},{"element":3}]
```

I am developing in ionic, and in modern cell phones it works. but in cell phones with versions of 4.4 it does not work and this error appears.

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."
```

What alternative can I do using good practice?

Comment: Looks like spread operator is not supported. Check the version of the browser and support for spread operator.

Comment: ok, but what good practice can I follow, what do you advise me, I would not like to do a cycle "for", maybe there is a better way

Comment: use Babel if you need to support new Javascript syntax for old browsers

Comment: Did you try to remove the syntax error for data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by Barun, the `...` spread syntax isn't supported. Use `Array.concat` to append the elements from `data` array to `my_array` array:

```
$scope.my_array=[];
$scope.my_array.push({"element":1});
var data= [{"element":2},{"element":3}];
$scope.my_array = $scope.my_array.concat(data);
console.log($scope.my_array);
```

For more information on JavaScript spread syntax:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax